# Oracle : Refuse Connection Listener Error

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jndi

I try to connect Oracle database using Java.

I am receiving the following error:

```
 Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection   with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

I am sure that my Java code is fine since i succeeded to connect a PostgresDB earlier.

This is my `context.xml` :

```
 <Resource      name="jdbc/TestDB" 
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                username="admin" 
                password="password" 
                driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:1521:cuat/"/>
```

Maybe my connecting URL is in a wrong format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the connection. `context.xml` in itself is not enough for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Oracle makes a distinction between service names and SID-s (identifiers). You may try

url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:1521/cuat" (if cuat is a service name, rather than a SID, use / , not :)

Anyway, check the tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: So, what's in the tnsnames.ora file? (the service names and SID-s should be declared there)

Comment: Some tools, especially those designed to be compatible with Oracle 9, are not very sensitive to service name/SID differences but it somehow is important for the thin driver. Just try the other url format and see if it works.

Comment: you need the service name not the SID, esp true if it's a 12c database with multitenant option

Answer (score 0):

The URL looks correct. The error you are receiving is that the tns listener on your machine (look for a file called `tnsnames.ora`) is not completely up to date with your database. Refresh this file and the connection should work.

Comment: sorry i am not aware of it. connecting oracle database is in different pc. whether tnsname.ora I need to create ? where it has to be placed?

Answer (score 0):

The listener isn't servicing a database SID or SERVICE named 'cuat'

Check the listener and make sure you've got the name right.

On the server you can run "lsnrctl status" for a list of services.

Comment: same url & sid i provided in db visualizer ide and i am able to connect the db. but couldn't via application.

Comment: database is not in my machine then how i have that file. i am just trying to connect via application. also through ide i am able to connect

Comment: what version of Oracle, 11 or 12? post a screenshot of your connection properties in dbvisualizer